# Передача информации между формами

Tags: c#, winforms

Задача следующая. Нужно чтобы в форме Form2 был доступ к данным, созданным в классе stroka из формы Form1 (иными словами – обеспечить работу с экземпляром класса strokа) 
В конце листнга создание класса sroka, в котором есть некая переменная типа стринг.

Листинг в форме 1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private stroka str; //делаю ссылку на класс
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        str = new stroka(); // создаю экземпляр
        str.a = "asdfg";        // вот передать значения переменных без
        textBoxMain.Text = str.a; // проблем, но речь не об этом.
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void buttonMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        str.a = textBoxMain.Text; // По нажатию кнопки открывается вторая
                    // форма Form2. Данные передаются без      проблем 
                    // Но речь не об этом)))
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(str); // А вот и ссылка на объект и плавно переходим
                     // ко второму листингу.
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
}

class stroka
{
    public string a;
}
}
```

Листинг 2. Форма 2.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private stroka str2; // Делаю указатель

    public Form2(stroka Astr) // И вот тут начинается. Подчеркивает
                // Form2 синей волнистой и пишет… (см текст ниже)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        str2 = Astr;

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Вот что пишет:

> «Ошибка   1   Несовместимость по
> доступности: доступность типа
> параметра
> "WindowsFormsApplication1.stroka" ниже
> доступности метода
> "WindowsFormsApplication1.Form2.Form2(WindowsFormsApplication1.stroka)"C:...\Form2.cs»

Ковырялся бы и дальше сам, но наткнулся в сети на похожий код, потом тютелька в тютельку сделал как там, и все равно выходит ошибку.

Comment: Попробуй сделать класс stroka public.

Comment: Ребята, спасибо! Тиныч особо за подробный ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых откройте класс для других модулей.

```
public class stroka  
{  
     public string a;  
}
```

Если не указать зону видимости, то класс автоматически неявно становится private, т.е. виден только внутри модуля в котором он описан.

---

Во-вторых, если вы используете класс **stroka** в нескольких модулях программы, то разумнее будет вынести и его самого в отдельный модуль. С вас не убудет.

---

В-третьих следите за пространствами имен (namespace). Если у вас форма1 в пространстве имен **namespace1**, а форма2 в пространстве **namespace2**, то они друг друга не увидят, пока вы не покажите модулям эти пространства, например:

```
using namespace2;  // для формы1
```

Comment: Ребята, спасибо! Тиныч особо за подробный ответ!

Comment: пожалуйста